# What is the difference between Params and Body in Postman

Tags: request, postman, put

In postman, what is the difference between the `Params` and the `Body` tabs?. I noticed that when I was trying to perform a `PUT` request, if I add the `key` and `value` in `Params` my `PUT` request doesn't seem to update what I intend to update but if I perform the `PUT` request in `Body` and have the `form-data` selected then the intended update happens.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Params correspond to the request parameters that are appended to the request URL.they are most used with GET requests. On the other hand, **Body** is the actual request body (usually it defines the request payload or the data that needs to be processed by the request). PUT and POST requests read usually the data from the body of the request and not from the params.

Comment: What is the reason for PUT and POST requests using the body instead of params?

Comment: one reason is security, the params will not be exposed in the URL

Comment: One more note. Body tab is used to handle JSON/XML format data, you can't put JSON/XML data in Params tab in Postman